# Is there a way of making a Linux block device which is just an offset into an existing block device?

Tags: linux, block-device

Is there a way of making a Linux block device which is just an offset into an existing block device?

i.e. `/dev/sdo`'s block zero is `/dev/sda`'s block 100, and `/dev/sdo` is consequently 100 blocks smaller than `/dev/sda`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

man losetup:

```
   -o, --offset offset
          The data start is moved offset bytes into the specified file  or
          device.
```